# Test my site with wapiti?

Tags: security, wapiti

I ran wapiti with these args. In just a few seconds it finished and the report says there are no vulnerabilities. I remember one time it took many minutes to scan (it wasnt on my local machine tho) and i got many vulnerabilities. I can't remember the args i used. What args may i use to test agaisnt more attacks?

```
wapiti.py http://localdev.com/ -s / -o o2/
```